# How to save coordinates values with respect to its id in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am beginner in python and writing a script where we input some data to an algorithm and it return the  detected id of the data along with the coordinates values `(x, y)`. The algorithm keeps returning the updated values of coordinates till the data is there and once the data is gone, it returns nothing or any other data coordinate.

Below is the code:

```
data_dict = data_fetch.update(data)
```

returned `data_dict` is an `ordered dict` which I can access like below:

```
for (data_id, data_coord) in data_dict.items():
    print(data_id)    # to print the id of the data
    print(data_coord) # to print the data coordinates
```

`output:`
`0`
`{634, 972}`

I need to save the values of coordinates for each id in dict or in list, so that once the data id is no longer present, I can access all the coordinates value i.e. x and y values of data id and plot it in a graph using `matplotlib`.

Comment: You could json as a format to save your data in; it's very straightforward to save a Python dict as json. But there are many more formats that may suitable for your case though; search around.

Comment: `points[data_id] = data_coord`

Answer (score 1):

You can `update` a dictionary so you could do this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data_dict = OrderedDict()

# then do this as many times as required:
data_dict.update(data_fetch.update(data))
```

You may not need to use `OrderedDict` if the ordering isn't important to you.

If the same coordinates keep being updated and you need all the values try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
stored_values = defaultdict(list)

new_values = data_fetch.update(data)
for key,value in new_values.items():
    stored_values[key].append(value)
```

Each key (id) will store a list of all the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks.I have tried this and this keeps updating the `data_dict` and not append. I need to save all the values.

Comment: So it keeps updating the coordinates for the same id and you need to save ALL those different values?

Comment: yes it keeps updating the same id coordinate value and I need to save all different values.

Comment: I will add to my answer.